# Auto insert text at a newline in vim

Tags: vim, latex

I am editing a LaTeX file with vim. When I am in the `\begin{itemize}` environment, is there any way to tell vim to autoinsert `\item` whenever I open a new line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
function CR()
    if searchpair('\\begin{itemize}', '', '\\end{itemize}', '')
        return "\r\\item"
    endif
    return "\r"
endfunction
inoremap <expr><buffer> <CR> CR()
```

Put this into your `.vim/ftplugins/tex.vim` file (or any `.vim` inside `.vim/ftplugins/tex` directory).

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend  http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net. This package defines several maps useful for latex.
In particular for inserting \item you press `<ATL-I>`

Comment: Thanks, this worked great. Although I may be pushing the envelope a little bit, is there any way where `\item` is added whenever a new line is opened automatically without having to rely on alt-I?

Comment: In vim-latex, you can say `EIT` to start an `itemize` environment.  vim-latex provides other shortcuts too.

Answer (score 1):

I know noting about latex but I think it is a good idea to search in vim scripts

[use the search button up left :D](http://www.vim.org/)

for example search for

latex auto completion

Answer (score 1):

I can hit Cntl-I and it'll put it in for me in either normal mode or insert mode. This is what I put in my .vimrc:

```
:imap <C-i> \item 
:nmap <C-i> o\item
```

Note that there is a space at the end of `\item`.

Answer (score 1):

I hacked the script ZyX supplied and came up with this. It adds support for the `o` and `O` commands. It does *not* require LaTeX-VIM.

```
function AddItem()
  if searchpair('\\begin{itemize}', '', '\\end{itemize}', '')
    return "\\item "
  else
    return ""
  endif
endfunction

inoremap <expr><buffer> <CR> "\r".AddItem()
nnoremap <expr><buffer> o "o".AddItem()
nnoremap <expr><buffer> O "O".AddItem()
```

Comment: Another modification would be `inoremap <expr><buffer> <CR> getline('.') =~ '\item $' ? '<c-w><c-w>' : '<CR>'.AddItem()` which automatically removes the `\item` if you press two times <CR>. Taken from https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/issues/455

Answer (score 1):

#### Extended Version of Answer by Samad Lotia and ZyX

Place this in your `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim`

```
function! AddItem()
  let [end_lnum, end_col] = searchpairpos('\\begin{', '', '\\end{', 'nW')
  if match(getline(end_lnum), '\(itemize\|enumerate\|description\)') != -1
    return "\\item "
  else
    return ""
  endif
endfunction
inoremap <expr><buffer> <CR> getline('.') =~ '\item $' 
  \ ? '<c-w><c-w>' 
  \ : (col(".") < col("$") ? '<CR>' : '<CR>'.AddItem() )
nnoremap <expr><buffer> o "o".AddItem()
nnoremap <expr><buffer> O "O".AddItem()
```

**Improvements**

- auto-insert of `\item` also happens for environments `enumerate` and `description`
- auto-insert of `\item` only happens if the immediate surrounding environment is one of the three (`itemize/enumerate/description`). It does not happen in following circumstance

```
  \begin{itemize}
    \item
       \begin{minipage}
        <CURSOR>
       \end{minipage}
  \end{itemize}
```

- auto-insert of `\item` only happens if you are at the end of the line
- deletion of auto inserted `\item` by pressing `<CR>` a second time. If one wants to add some indention in this case, change `'<c-w><c-w>'` to `'<c-w><c-w><c-t>'`.